# Powershell Textbox Catching Results

Tags: powershell, forms, textbox

Scenario:

I have a form with TEXTBOXA, TEXTBOXB and a BUTTON.
BUTTON will add all the groups entered in TEXTBOXB to TEXTBOXA which is working properly.
But it does not inform me if any groups failed to be added.

So I would like to add log catching.

All outcomes from the For Loop should be showed in TextboxB.
Currently, it will show only that it completed without alerting me of any errors.

Here's the code:

```
Foreach ($group in $groups)
{
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members $loginid.text -credential $admin -Confirm:$false
$Output2.text = "All Groups Added. Please review and confirm."
clear-content $bulkgrouppath
```

Tried using write-error and write-output but I don;t think I'm using it correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`try / catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-7.4) for error handling, as an example of how it would look with your current implementation:

```
foreach ($group in $groups) {
    try {
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members $loginid.text -Credential $admin -Confirm:$false
        $Output2.Text += "'$group' processed successfully.`n"
        Clear-Content $bulkgrouppath
    }
    catch {
        # assign the error message to the TextBoxB
        $Output2.Text += "Failed to process '$group' with error: '$($_.Exception.Message)'.`n" 
        # additionally you can output it to the console for additional troubleshooting
        Write-Error $_
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked. The error was caught in the console but the textbox only showed the success message:
This should be fine but would love it if it would also output to the textbox as it goes through the list

Like this:




Good Group success 
Bad Group was not recognized
Good Group success

Comment: What's the name of `TEXTBOXA` in your actual code? I thought that was `$Output2` ? @christianrondon

Comment: sorry Yes it's output2.

Comment: @christianrondon try with the last edit of my answer. I'm not sure what you're looking for

Comment: I think the issue is I wasn't sure where to add the append part

$Output2.Text += $_.Exception.Message + [System.Environment]::NewLine

Comment: if you want to append text to the textbox you can use `+=` as in my edited answer: `$Output2.Text += ....`

Comment: Working now THANKS!

Comment: @christianrondon awesome! :) glad to help